# Expected value of a biased coin toss

Tags: probability

Please help me to calculate expected value.

Consider a biased coins such that the probability for tails is p and the probability for heads is 1-p. Coin tossing continued until the coin shows heads. When you toss a coin, you pay 1.

H:     $1-p$

TH:    $2p(1-p)$

TTH:   $3p^2(1-p)$

.     .

.     .

.     .

In sum, $E[X]=1+p^2+P^3+.....-np^{n-1} = \frac{1-p^n}{1-p}-np^{n-1}$.

Since $p^{n-1}$ reaches zero exponentially, $-np^{n-1}$ can be neglected.

$E[X]= \frac{1-p^n}{1-p}$

I am not sure my derivation is correct or not. But, it seems this cases has a unique name who invented this game such as Bernoulli trial. Is anybody know the name of this game and how to drive the expected value?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What sort of game is this where you keep on paying 1 for each toss ! What do you get in return ? Or are we just to find the sum of (1-p) + 2p(1-p) + ....

Comment: **What** are you trying to find the expected value of? At first I thought it would be the expected value of the number of flips to get the first head but then you say "when you toss a coin you pay 1". Do you mean that you are trying to win money? If so, how are you paid? Are you paid 1 for each time you flip a coin without getting a head or for the total number of flips until you get a head? Please tell us exactly what you are asking!

Comment: I think you are asking about the expectation of a random variable $X$ that has *geometric distribution* with parameter $1-p$ (unusual choice of name).   We have $E(X)=\frac{1}{1-p}$.  The expectation of a geometric random variable, and sums of the type you are interested in, have often been discussed on MSE.

Comment: This game will end if I will get heads. If not, I need to keep paying 1 for each toss. The expected value means here is average cost for it.

Answer (score 3):

Okay.  Let's see.

$X$ is the count of tosses until the first head.   This is a random variable of *some* distribution.   I wonder what?

We have that $\mathsf P(X=x) = p^{x-1}(1-p)$ where $p$ is the probability of getting a tail on any particular toss, for $x\in \{1, \ldots, \infty\}$

Then $\mathsf E(X) = (1-p)\sum_{x=1}^\infty p^{x-1}$ , and that series is a *geometric series*.   (This may be a clue as to the name of our mystery distribution. Hmmm.)

$$\mathsf E(X) = \frac 1 {1-p}$$

---

An alternative derivation is to use the Law of Iterated Expectation (aka the Law of Total Expectation), and partition on the result of the next toss.  If we get a tail, we're up one count and the experiment repeats; otherwise experiment ends and the count is $1$.   So the expectation is recursively defined:

$$\mathsf E(X) = p \cdot (1+\mathsf E(X)) + (1-p)\cdot 1
\\[2ex] \therefore \mathsf E(X) = \frac 1{1-p}$$

Answer (score 1):

With your clarification, what you are looking for is the sum of

$ S = (1-p) + 2p(1-p) + 3p^2(1-p) + 4p^3(1-p) + ......$

Now $S\times p =\; p(1-p) + \;\;2p^2(1-p) + 3p^2(1-p) + ....$

Subtracting the two term by term arranged against each other vertically,

$S(1-p) = (1-p) + p(1-p) + p^2(1-p) + p^3(1-p) + .......$

$S = E(X) = 1 + p + p^2 + p^3 + ....$

which is a geometric series with sum = $E(X) = \dfrac{1}{1-p}$